# uiimageview not showing image in view controller

Tags: xcode, swift3, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to display a chart image in my view controller. I have an image called 'powerchart' in my assets, but I cannot get it to display in the view controller. I am trying to build the app programatically, therefore not using storyboard. code below. I've tried using several combinations of UIImage. functions, but cannot get the image to load. Any help would be appreciated

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MarketViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        navigationController?.title = "Market"


        view.addSubview(marketChart)
        setupMarketScreen()

    }

//    create chart
    let marketChart: UIImageView = {
        let chart = UIImageView()
        chart.image = UIImage.init(imageLiteralResourceName: "powerchart")
        return chart
    }()

    func setupMarketScreen() {

        marketChart.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive=true
        marketChart.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive=true
        marketChart.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive=true
        marketChart.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive=true

    }
}
```

Comment: code works with 'chart.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare This Way. Below code works fine for me.

```html
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    /*
    let marketChart: UIImageView = {
        let chart = UIImageView()
        chart.image = UIImage.init(imageLiteralResourceName: "backimg3.jpeg")
        return chart
    }() */
    let marketChart:UIImageView = UIImageView.init(image: UIImage (named: "backimg3.jpeg"))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
           self.view.addSubview(marketChart)
    }


}
```

Comment: i never assign image as you were.I tried with your way but it was not working.

Comment: if you want help from me you can contact me . sagarkoyani4u@gmail.com